# Multiple channels in golang.org/x/crypto/ssh server

Tags: go, ssh, server, channel

Does the ssh.ServerConn type in the golang SSH package support multiple ssh channels over the same transport?
I am writing a simulator for a device that allows several services over SSH and it seems that the SSH server implementation in Go only supports one channel at a time. I know the client initiates an SSH connection then opens several channels as needed for tcp port forwarding and SFTP, but it seems that the ServerConn type only accepts one channel at a time.

I have a Goroutine to service the <-chan NewChannel that contains the for loop:

```
for c := range chans {
```

where chans is the passed channel, and I have confirmed that after accepting the first channel nothing is blocking and the end of the for loop is reached, but the next iteration won't occur unless the first channel is closed.

What am i missing here? Shouldn't the ssh.ServerConn pass a new ssh channel request from the client to the chans channel as soon as it is requested rather than waiting for any existing channels to close?

Is there a configuration parameter that I missed?

Comment: Do you get an error when you call `OpenChannel` from the server?

Comment: It's the client on the other end of the connection that is opening the channels... I'm using .Accept() on my end, then spawning Goroutines to service the requests and handle read/write. The first channel opens fine and is actively communicating, but when the remote client tries to open an additional channel on the other end, the ssh.NewChannel doesn't arrive in the Go channel unless the first channel has been forced closed.

Comment: The server can accept multiple channel requests, it sounds like you are not servicing a blocking go channel someone in the code. Please create a [mre] that show the problem you're having.

Comment: I finally figured out the issue - the problem turned out to be in the client all along. The client was opening a separate transport for each service, rather than a single transport with multiple channels. I was fixated on looking only at channels to realize the client was re-initializing the entire connection when I interrupted the channel. One I allowed the program to accept multiple connections each with a separate SSH transport, the client opened up one for each service.